# Removing leading zero from string in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, attribute-table, expression, leading-zero

How can I in QGIS through Expression calculator remove leading zeroes i.e. the `0` leading from a string?

| Original_Value | New_Value |
| --- | --- |
| 09 | 9 |
| 0150 | 150 |
| 09850 | 9850 |
| 054a23 | 54a23 |
| 5837 | 5837 |

Something like the example above.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following should be working :

```
 regexp_replace("field_to_modify",'\\A0','')
```

Only if your aim is to strip a *(=one)* leading zero ...

Comment: It worked like a charm thank you! But what does \\A mean and where can I find the documentation for these?

Comment: \ stands for this https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#morechars and `\A` declares this https://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html#A

Comment: \A stands for 'start of string' ...just google 'regex tutorial' and you will find plenty of ressources ...

Comment: Add an asterisc to the expression for one or more 0 (zero). 

    regexp_replace("field_to_modify",'\\A0*','')

Answer (score 7):

Simply you can use the [`regexp_replace()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#regexp-replace) function in the following expression:

```
regexp_replace("FieldName", '^0', '')
```

`'^0'` means select the `0` that is located at the beginning of string.

`"FieldName"` is the input field that you want to remove the zero from.

Here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest making a number attribute column and populating this new column with `"OLD_Column" * 1`

Comment: The original column is a string with non-digit characters.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, if there are only numeric characters in your field and you have *multiple* leading zeros, is to convert the field to an integer using `to_int("FIELD_NAME")` so `0000535` becomes `535`.